# jdbc connection refused while configuring in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using oracle 12c with jar ojdbc7 to configure DB in hibernate.  but i'm getting following error :

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at com.vikas.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:21)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
... 14 more
```

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

```
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:272)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
... 19 more
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows: 
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1522/DevDb
        SYSTEM
        oracle123

```
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

can somebody help me out to resolve this issue.

---

It says

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

my SID given is correct.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using some other tool, for example SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 0):

your jdbc connect string is only almost correct

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1522/DevDb
```

This is correct

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1522/DevDb
```

Also, make sure to try to login using sqlplus before you try the ORM way.

Comment: Hi Bjarte... it helped... but now there is one more problem i'm getting Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: Can you connect using sqlplus? Are you sure about 1522? What is the output of  C:\>tnsping DevDb

Comment: thanks a lot bro.. it working now...  you were right.. server had to get started.. and from the string                                       jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1522/DevDb   "//" had to be removed so its working fine now...  :)

Answer (score 0):

your settings are correct, nothing to do with settins in a persistence.xml->older(hibernate.cfg.xml)

I had seen for a short time in a application in the middle of the night although this excepiton in server-logg but not in app-logg. I analysed that and my logic is handled right, this means this is a oracleXE bug or a app-server bug or ORM-Provider bug(hibernate)! this is sure, the app is running since months but this exeption never occured until know and the point is that nobdy invoked a client call! I restarted the server, every thing seems to be correct.

Maybe it can happen that if a network-connection was down for a short time and so serialization for data-objects between server and database could not be reachable, I don't know, it can be happen, because for example JBoss is caching data!